# Cucumber Message : To disable this message, add cucumber.publish.quiet=true to cucumber.properties

Tags: android-studio, dependency-injection, jvm, cucumber, android-espresso

I write code using cucumber android studio and espresso but I couldnt implement cucumber to my project.I get the following error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJSVn.png)

Later I created new properties file such as :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYCUc.png)

But it didnt work.

My grandle file :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.loginexample"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testApplicationId "com.example.loginexample.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.loginexample.Instumentation"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'



    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.5.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    //Not change
    androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.5'

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:2.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.4'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:6.6.0'
    implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-core:6.6.0'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.6.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }


}
```

Project grandle file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my cucumber file :

```
package com.tests;


import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(

        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:" + Runner.REPORT_PATH + "cucumber-html-report",
                "pretty:" + Runner.REPORT_PATH + "cucumber-report.json",
                "junit:" + Runner.REPORT_PATH + "cucumber.xml"
        },
        features = "assets/features",
        tags = "@shortSanity")
public class Runner {

    public static final String REPORT_PATH = "data/data/" + com.example.loginexample.BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/cucumber-reports/";

}
```

I created properties file to  src/test/resources/cucumber.properties path and I added as below but I didnt work still

```
cucumber.publish.quiet=true
```

Comment: Are your tests running from under `/src/test` ?

Comment: yes @AlexeyR. true